# How to get the same response pattern when doing fluentvalidation manually

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

When I use fluentvalidation in the normal form I have one response, but when I tried to use it mannually I have another response, how can I get the same response manually?

**Normal Response**

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-dc7d6c683021ab4e8b3e2db42748e569-ec9d9967213d614c-00",
    "errors": {
        "LicensePlate": [
            "'License Plate' não pode ser nulo."
        ]
    }
}
```

**Manual**

```
public ActionResult<ResponseUpdateLeadVehicleDTO> ChangeLeadPlate1(int id, [CustomizeValidator(Skip = true)]RequestUpdateLeadVehicleDTO request)
{    
  if (!validation.IsValid)
  {
    validation.AddToModelState(ModelState, null);
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }
}
```

**response**

```
{
    "LicensePlate": [
        "'License Plate' não pode ser nulo."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, right after posted the question. Thanks to Kevin Smith at [Adding errors to model state and returning bad request within asp.net core 3.1](https://kevsoft.net/2020/02/09/adding-errors-to-model-state-and-returning-bad-request-within-asp-net-core-3-1.html)

We need to injecting in ***ApiBehaviorOptions*** in to our action, these options are used to describe how the api should behavior. One of the options is a factory to create the response back from the api when the model state is invalid, this is called ***InvalidModelStateResponseFactory***. We can call this factory with the ***ControllerContext*** which will give us back an IActionResult in which we can return back to the action.

```
public IActionResult ChangeLeadPlate1(int id,
  [CustomizeValidator(Skip = true)] RequestUpdateLeadVehicleDTO request,
  [FromServices] IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions> apiBehaviorOptions)
{   
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return apiBehaviorOptions.Value.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory(ControllerContext);
}
```